# Codeigniter 3 - Ajax File Upload (You did not select a file to upload)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Controller:

```
function post()
{
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        show_404();
        exit;
    }

    $data['result'] = false;

    $config['upload_path']          = base_url().'userfiles/customer';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']             = 100000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $file = $this->input->post('userfile');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($file))
    {
        $data['result'] = true;
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $data['error'] = $error;
}
    else
    {
        $data['result'] = true;
        $data_upload = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $data['success'] = $data_upload;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="package">Package :</label>
        <select class="package form-control" id="package" name="package">
            <option value="none">Please select..</option>
            <?php foreach($package as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id_order_package'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <div class="error" id="msg_package"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="price">Price ( Rp ) :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="" disabled>
        <div class="error" id="msg_price"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="days">Days :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="days" id="days" placeholder="" disabled>
        <div class="error" id="msg_days"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="userfile">File :</label>
        <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" class="form-control">
        <div class="error" id="msg_userfile"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="description">Description :</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
        <div class="error" id="msg_description"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group center">
        <div class="btn btn-primary">ORDER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
        $('#msg_package').html(' ');
        $('#msg_userfile').html(' ');
        $('#msg_description').html(' ');

        if($('#package').val() == 'none') {
            $('#msg_package').html('Please select package');
        } else if($('#userfile').val() == '') {
            $('#msg_userfile').html('This field is required');
        } else if($('#description').val() == '') {
            $('#msg_description').html('This field is required');
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                url     : '<?php echo base_url() ?>account_order/add/post',
                type    : 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                processData: false,
                data    : { userfile: $('#userfile')[0].files , price: $('#price').val() , days: $('#days').val() },
                success: function( data ) {

                       if(!data['result']){

                       }else{
                           alert(data['error']);
                       }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But, i get an error

```
{"result":true,"error":{"error":"<p>You did not select a file to upload.<\/p>"}}
```

I tried to post data & file from ajax, but it doesn't work.
My question is how to fix that error? Why the controller can't read userfile's content?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put your inputs in form and give the form id='your_form_id' then send your data by this way in javascript:

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("your_form_id"));
```

then replace this line `data    : { userfile: $('#userfile')[0].files , price: $('#price').val() , days: $('#days').val() },`

with this `data: data,`

also set this after `data: data,`:

```
async: false,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean "put your inputs in form and give the form id='your_form_id'" ? Could you give a spesific answer? :D

Comment: i didn't see form tag in your HTMl code, so I mean form tag <form id='your_form_id'></form>