# CodeIgniter "You did not select a file to upload."

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and Ajax, so please be patient with me.

I am attempting a school assignment in which we have to upload a file to our server. I tried to follow the instructions but I receive the error "You did not select a file to upload." Can someone help me please?

Here is my javascript

```
function uploadFile(){        
    data = {};
    data['file']= document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/conference/presentation/changes/file',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });}
```

And here is the code from CI

```
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'./';
    $config['allowed_tyeps'] = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        echo $upload_error;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have also attempted
data = new FormData();
file =document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
data.append('testfile', file);
But I still get the "you did not select a file to upload" error.

Comment: Please put all pertinent information in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter 3 - Ajax File Upload (You did not select a file to upload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151367/codeigniter-3-ajax-file-upload-you-did-not-select-a-file-to-upload)

Comment: Thank you buzz3791. I attempted the solution in Codeigniter 3 - Ajax File Upload (You did not select a file to upload) but I still get "you did not select a file to upload." error.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter probably needs data in multipart form data which would require a FormData object.

```
function uploadFile(){        
    var data = new FormData;
    data.append('file', document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/conference/presentation/changes/file',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });}
```

Also, specify the name of the file to upload in code igniter

```
$this->upload->do_upload('file')
```

Comment: Hi Musa, thank you for the quick response. I attempted to use the FormData but the return is still "you did not select a file to upload."

Comment: Thank you Musa! The adding the name of the file worked !Thank you!